how to add Mono<String> from loop to List<String>
have written reactive application using springboot-3.x,webflux and need to add String from  Mono to List inside for loop.
have implemented below code:
Flux<Mono<String>> IdFlux = Flux.empty();
matchesByComp.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(key -> {        
        Mono<String> IdMono1 = reactiveRedisOperations.get(key,id);
        IdFlux.concat(IdMono1);

});

From above code again unable to convert Flux<Mono<String>> IdFlux to List<String>.

Instead of trying to modify Flux<Mono> inside the loop, you can map each Mono to a Flux by merging them into a single Flux. Then, you can collect the results in a List.
Flux<String> idFlux = Flux.fromIterable(matchesByComp.keySet())
    .flatMap(key -> reactiveRedisOperations.get(key, id));


List<String> idList = idFlux.collectList().block();


Hi @peppe71-19, thanks!! for your response. i need to convert without block() method

You can't. The block() method is the way to break out of reactive and get back to the current thread.
